# What contributions have Chaincode developers made to Bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development

Related question: [What contributions have Blockstream developers made to the Bitcoin project?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/42420/what-contributions-have-blockstream-developers-made-to-the-bitcoin-project)

Blockstream's contributions and involvement in Bitcoin is discussed a lot. I want to know Chaincode Labs's involvement, contributions and influence in Bitcoin.

Comment: Blockstream co-founders were much more public than Chaincode co-founders and developers (with the exception of John Newbery and Matt Corallo who co-founded both I think) so it is harder to answer other than to look at Git commits. It looks like the focus has been on P2P though there are individuals working on specific projects (e.g ryanofsky process separation in Core). Pieter Wuille and Murch have recently joined and they have different interests and are more public facing. For someone outside the tent(s) I have found it much easier to follow what Blockstream is doing than Chaincode :)

Comment: _"John Newbery and Matt Corallo who co-founded both I think"_ Interesting. Yes it is easier to follow what Blockstream is doing.

Comment: To be clear Matt Corallo co-founded both (I think). John Newbery was one of the first hires of Chaincode but wasn't involved with Blockstream. But John has done the majority of public facing stuff at Chaincode (Conferences, Residency, PR review club etc) until he moved to Brink

Comment: @MichaelFolkson do you have sources on Matt or John co-founding Chaincode? The site is pretty unambiguous in claiming the founders to be Morcos and Daftuar (even all the way back on archive.org) so I'm curious where you're getting that from

Comment: See above comment "John Newbery was one of the first *hires* of Chaincode" I thought Matt was there from the beginning and organized first residency. But yeah if the site says that then that is the significantly more authoritative resource!

Answer (score 2):

One thing that hasn't been mentioned yet is the Chaincode Seminars, where anyone that are interested can apply to attend.
It's a great way to learn about the fundamentals and have something to build on if you want to code in the industry. There are plenty of developers in the industry that started out there.

https://chaincode.gitbook.io/seminars/
https://learning.chaincode.com/

Answer (score 0):

Few things that were mentioned on Chaincode's website:

1. Chaincode engineers develop, review, test and maintain Bitcoin Core
2. Chaincode has contributed research and design for many of the recent improvements in the Bitcoin protocol, e.g. Erlay and Compact Blocks.
3. The Chaincode Residency is a program for engineers to develop experience with Bitcoin. Chaincode has hosted several residencies focused on the Bitcoin protocol, Bitcoin Core, Lightning Network applications and the Lightning protocol.
4. Bitcoin Optech helps Bitcoin users and businesses integrate scaling technologies through workshops, documentation, weekly newsletters, original research, case studies and announcements.
5. The Chaincode Podcast brings you interviews with the most influential Bitcoin engineers about Bitcoin protocol development.

https://chaincode.com/projects